# Can't access the last attribute of an object in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a *.mat file that I am loading in python via :

```
matFile = scipy.io.load('*.mat',squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)
```

The mat file contains array of two objects and many attributes inside the objects. When I try to iterate through the attributes of those objects and try to append them to other variable, the last attribute is not iterated through and I can't collect value of the variable.

Here is an example:

lets assume the matFile contains the following structure:

```
matFile['some_data'].myObj[0].attr1 = 1
matFile['some_data'].myObj[0].attr2 = 2
matFile['some_data'].myObj[0].attr3 = 3
matFile['some_data'].myObj[0].attr4 = 4
matFile['some_data'].myObj[0].attr5 = 5
```

This is how I collect the data from those objects:

```
collect_data = []
for element in matFile['some_data'].myObj[0]
    collect_data.append(element)
```

No matter what I try the last element (lets say the attr5) is not going through the loop and I am not collecting the data.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Are you missing the colon at the end of the for loop declaration? Please, make sure you show the exact code you're using.

Comment: What's `scipy.io.load`? I get error: `AttributeError: module 'scipy.io' has no attribute 'load'`. Could it be that you're using `scipy.io.loadmat`?

Comment: What's the output of `print(matFile['some_data'].myObj[0].__dict__)`?

Comment: furas -> I've printed everything before I shared my problem.
Ignatius Reilly -> Yes, I was using the scipy.io.loadmat indeed.

I couldn't share the actual code out of confidential / sensitive data being there.
That's why I made a small snippet. And I know that If I had share the actual code you guys would have find the problem.

I've found the problem though.
The collecting data in my case was in a recursion which was hitting a corner case which I haven't thought through.

Thank you for you spared time for my problems=)